# Cannot execute .mp3 file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a script for Python that basically plays a sound every five seconds.

My code:

```
import time
import os

while True:
    path = '/Users/ColShell/Desktop/beep-08b.mp3'
    path.rstrip('/')
    os.system(path)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I get this error when executing:

```
sh: /Users/ColShell/Desktop/beep-08b.mp3: cannot execute binary file
```

Can anyone can help explain why please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to execute an MP3 file so of course it's throwing that error - try pasting `/Users/ColShell/Desktop/beep-08b.mp3` in your Terminal and see what happens.

Are you trying to play the file in the default system player instead? That would  depend on your OS - I'd assume MacOS X based on your path, so you can use `open` to call the default application for MP3 files:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["open", "/Users/ColShell/Desktop/beep-08b.mp3"])
```

However, it would be better to use an app designed to play sounds in the background and OSX has `afplay` for that, so:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["afplay", "/Users/ColShell/Desktop/beep-08b.mp3"])
```

But if you want to play your sounds directly in Python then there are a couple of options - I personally find [`playsound`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.2) to be one of the most elegant approaches so install it and then you can easily use it with:

```
import playsound

playsound.playsound("/Users/ColShell/Desktop/beep-08b.mp3")
```

As a bonus - it's (mostly) cross platform.

Comment: Thanks man this is what i was looking for. I thought it would open up the default application just by running the file so it was definitely a misunderstanding on my part.