# How to play a sound in python 3.6.1? Is this possible?

Tags: python, audio, timer

I tried to make a timer, here is my code

```
import time

timer = int(input("how long"))
s = 1
w = int(input("what is it"))
while s < w + 1:
    print (s)
    s = s + 1
time.sleep(10)
print ("your timer is done")
```

then sound loud beep`

Comment: Not exactly related, but here's how to play a sound: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260700/7553525 (last example)

Answer (score 2):

first install the library

```
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

then execute

```
python3 say_it_pyttsx3.py
```

cat say_it_pyttsx3.py

```
import pyttsx3 as pyttsx

what2Say = '\
    your timer is done \
    '

# Speaking engine
speakEngine = pyttsx.init()
speakEngine.say(what2Say)
speakEngine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: what library I am confused

Comment: what library and how to install it

Answer (score 1):

How to give out a beep depends greatly on your underlying system.  You could try by simply `print('\a')` which is supposed to do that.

Unfortunately, a lot of modern systems do not stick to that old rule.  Then you could try to tweak your system to honor the "bell" character or you could try to give out a beep using a completely different method, e. g. by playing a small sound file.

How to do this again depends greatly on your operating system etc.  You might want to tell us more about this.

On my Linux box, for instance, I use a commandline tool called `play` (from package `sox`) to play `.wav` and `.ogg` files, and `mpg123` to play `.mp3` files.  From Python you can start them e. g. using this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([
    'play', '-q', '/usr/share/sounds/KDE-K3B-Finish-Success.ogg' ],
  env={'AUDIODEV':'plughw:1,0'} )
```

Comment: I tried this but here is what happened.                                                                             how long0
what is it1
1
your timer is done

>>>                                                                                                                                 no sound?

Comment: File not found. How to use full path?

Comment: I guess you have no `play` installed.  What does `play` on the command line result in?  I installed it in Ubuntu by `sudo apt-get install sox`.

Answer (score 0):

This has similarly been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307501/6332918). In essence, you would need a third party library, but which you need depends on the type of sound you want to play, if you just want a basic beep or a supplied audio file, and multiple other factors, but they suggest [Snack](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) as a starting point. There is installation instructions on Snack's site and the linked answer suggests usage as simple as:

```
import snack
s = Sound() 
s.read('sound.wav') 
s.play()
```